# How do I move everything in a directory into a subdirectory?

Tags: shell, unix, sh

Usually, I

```
$ mkdir dirname
$ mv * dirname
mv: cannot move 'dirname' to a subdirectory of itself, 'dirname/dirname'
```

I don't see a problem with this, but I'm curious whether there are other solutions (particularly simple ones that don't result in an error message).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `mv * dirname` is the shell pattern expansion. `*`will be used to reference all files in the current directory, so it will also include you new dirname subdirectory. Therefore the error message.

To reference all but one file, try this:

`mv ~/Old/!(excludedFile) ~/New/` where excludedFile is "dirname" in your case. And naturally dirname is also the "New" directory. So `mv !(dirname) dirname`.